# How to draw a wide landscape table?

Tags: tables, formatting, landscape

I was trying to draw the table like this in the image below with my columns and data, couldn't get any idea how do I proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Reference Table]

```
\begin{document}    
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[]
    \caption{Comparison table}
    \label{tab:my-table}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
                            & Types of Images            & Transform Domain            & Nature & Number of keys                                                  & Chaotic System   used  & Resistance to   attacks                                    & Key Sensitivity & Entropy & PSNR     & MSE             & Encryption   Time(s) \\ \hline
    Bentham-Hukum           & Lena                       & Gyrator Transform, PTFT?    & -      & -                                                               & -                      & -                                                          & -               & 6.8906  & -        & 2.26 x 10   -22 & 1.35                 \\ \hline
    Optik,   Hukum+ Anshula & -                          & Fractional Hartely,         & -      & -                                                               & -                      & Yes                                                        & -               & -       & 316.12   & 5.70 x 10 -34   & -                    \\ \hline
    Yaoling   Zhou et al.   & Cover Lena image was used. & TVAL3 and wavelet transform & -      & -                                                               & Logistic map           & Yes, agaisnt Brute Force attacks   and Occlusional Attacks & -               &         & 32.00998 & -               & -                    \\ \hline
    Sachin,   Phool Singh   & Boy                        & Chirp Z Transform           & -      & 6 chaos parameters, 3 frequency   parameters and 2 private keys & Chaotic Tinkerbell Map & Yes                                                        & Very large      & 7.9875  & -        & 4.8818 x 10 4   & -                    \\ \hline
    Our Paper               & ABC                        & ABC                         & -      & -                                                               & ABC                    & ABC                                                        & -               & -       & -        & -               & -                    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Always make a short, but compileable test file which includes all the necessary packages etc.

Comment: The table in the image uses a formatted caption (see caption package, unless provided by document class).  It seems to use very large gaps between columns, so I'm guessing `tabuler*` `{\linewidth}` with `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`.

Answer (score 1):

- As starting point simce necessary document preamble for your table is unknown ...
- Two solution:

  - by use of the `tabularx` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{tight-spacing}
\small
\caption{Comparison table}
\label{tab:my-table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{12}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X |}}
    \hline
    & Types of Images   & Transform Domain      & Nature 
    & Number of keys    & Chaotic System used   & Resistance to   attacks   
    & Key Sensitivity   & Entropy               & PSNR     
    & MSE               & Encryption   Time(s)          \\ 
    \hline
Bentham-Hukum           
    & Lena              & Gyrator Transform, PTFT?  & - & -
    & -                 & -                     & - & 6.8906  
    & -                 & \num{2.26e-22}        & 1.35      \\ 
    \hline
Optik,   Hukum+ Anshula & -                     & Fractional Hartely,         
    & -                 & -                     & -                      
    & Yes               & -                     & -       
    & 316.12            & \num{5.70e-34}        & -         \\
    \hline
Yaoling   Zhou et al.   & Cover Lena image was used. & TVAL3 and wavelet transform 
    & -                 & -                     & Logistic map           
    & Yes, agaisnt Brute Force attacks   and Occlusional Attacks 
                        & -                     &         
    & 32.00998          & -                     & -         \\ 
    \hline
Sachin,   Phool Singh   & Boy                   & Chirp Z Transform           
    & -                 & 6 chaos parameters, 3 frequency   parameters and 2 private keys 
                                                & Chaotic Tinkerbell Map 
    & Yes               & Very large            & 7.9875  
    & -                 & \num{4.8818e4}       & -         \\ 
    \hline
Our Paper               & ABC                   & ABC                         
    & -                 & -                     & ABC                    
    & ABC               & -                     & -       
    & -                 & -                     & -         \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- a wee bit more sophisticated by use of the `tabularray` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf,
            labelsep=quad,
            singlelinecheck=off]
            {caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\leavevmode\vfil
\begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{tight-spacing}
\small
\caption{Comparison table}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {*{3}{X[1.1, cmd=\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}]}
                             X[0.8, cmd=\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}]
                        *{3}{X[1.5, cmd=\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}]}
                        *{3}{X[0.8, cmd=\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}]}
                        *{2}{X[cmd=\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}]}
                        },
             colsep=3pt,
             row{1} = {cmd=\Centering}
             }
    & Types of Images   & Transform Domain      & Nature 
    & Number of keys    & Chaotic System used   & Resistance to   attacks   
    & Key Sensitivity   & Entropy               & PSNR     
    & MSE               & Encryption   Time(s)          \\ 
Bentham-Hukum           
    & Lena              & Gyrator Transform, PTFT?  & - & -
    & -                 & -                     & - & 6.8906  
    & -                 & \num{2.26e-22}        & 1.35      \\ 
Optik,   Hukum+ Anshula & -                     & Fractional Hartely,         
    & -                 & -                     & -                      
    & Yes               & -                     & -       
    & 316.12            & \num{5.70e-34}        & -         \\
Yaoling   Zhou et al.   & Cover Lena image was used. & TVAL3 and wavelet transform 
    & -                 & -                     & Logistic map           
    & Yes, agaisnt Brute Force attacks   and Occlusional Attacks 
                        & -                     &         
    & 32.00998          & -                     & -         \\ 
Sachin,   Phool Singh   & Boy                   & Chirp Z Transform           
    & -                 & 6 chaos parameters, 3 frequency   parameters and 2 private keys 
                                                & Chaotic Tinkerbell Map 
    & Yes               & Very large            & 7.9875  
    & -                 & \num{4.8818e4}       & -         \\ 
Our Paper               & ABC                   & ABC                         
    & -                 & -                     & ABC                    
    & ABC               & -                     & -       
    & -                 & -                     & -         \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, thanks for this but I needed to have a landscape table in a portrait page, how do I that? Kinda new to Latex...

Comment: It is landscape page, but on screen turned for 90 degrees fors easy reading ... se position of page number! If you not like to see in such a way, replace \usepackage{pdflscape} with `Usepackage{lscape}` . And, please extend your code fragment to an MWE )Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document beginning with \documentclass` and end with `\end{documet}`

Comment: That works, thanks though!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double page float for the tabular. Makes only sense in a twosome document:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for demo
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

\Blindtext[15]

\hvFloat[sameHeight,doublePage,capPos=bottom]{table}{%
  \begin{tabular}{|P{2cm}|P{2cm}|P{3cm}|l|P{3cm}|l|P{3cm}|l|l|l|l|P{2cm}|}
    \hline
    & Types of Images            & Transform Domain            & Nature & Number of keys                                                  & Chaotic System   used  & Resistance to   attacks                                    & Key Sensitivity & Entropy & PSNR     & MSE             & Encryption   Time(s) \\ \hline
    Bentham-Hukum           & Lena                       & Gyrator Transform, PTFT?    & -      & -                                                               & -                      & -                                                          & -               & 6.8906  & -        & 2.26 x 10   -22 & 1.35                 \\ \hline
    Optik,   Hukum+ Anshula & -                          & Fractional Hartely,         & -      & -                                                               & -                      & Yes                                                        & -               & -       & 316.12   & 5.70 x 10 -34   & -                    \\ \hline
    Yaoling   Zhou et al.   & Cover Lena image was used. & TVAL3 and wavelet transform & -      & -                                                               & Logistic map           & Yes, agaisnt Brute Force attacks   and Occlusional Attacks & -               &         & 32.00998 & -               & -                    \\ \hline
    Sachin,   Phool Singh   & Boy                        & Chirp Z Transform           & -      & 6 chaos parameters, 3 frequency   parameters and 2 private keys & Chaotic Tinkerbell Map & Yes                                                        & Very large      & 7.9875  & -        & 4.8818 x 10 4   & -                    \\ \hline
    Our Paper               & ABC                        & ABC                         & -      & -                                                               & ABC                    & ABC                                                        & -               & -       & -        & -               & -                    \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}}
  {Comparison table}%
  {tab:my-table}
  
\Blindtext[15]

See tabular~\ref{tab:my-table}
  
\end{document}
```

[image]